How to remove GeoTIFF overlays certain geometry on the map
As shown in the below posted code, I instantiate an object from GeoTIFF class with configurations shown below. At run time, the tiff image overlays the desired geometry, but I can not remove it.
In code section below, it shows how I attempted to remove the tiff overlay using removeLayer but it does not remove anything.
I also tried this.#geoTIFFSource.clear() but also not was removed from the map.
Am i doing something wrong? I just want to remove the tiff overlay
note
The following line of code:
this.#mapInstance.removeLayer(tileLayerWebGL)

is not getting called immediately after addTileLayerWebGLToMap(), it gets called when the user clicks specific button, which means, it gets executed after the tiff is loaded
code
this.#geoTIFFSource = new GeoTIFF({
    wrapX: false,
    normalize: true,
    sources: [
      {
        blob: res,
        nodata: NaN,
        bands: [1],
        min: minNDVI,
        max: maxNDVI,
      },
    ],
});

const tileLayerWebGL = this.#mapBuilderInstance.addTileLayerWebGLToMap(
    this.#mapInstance, 
    this.#geoTIFFSource,
    this.listenToExtentOfDigitizedGeomForIndex(this.#featureRecentlyRequestedProcessing.get(DigitizePolygonConstants.CONST_DIGITIZED_FEATURE_PROPERTY_GEOM_ORDER.description) - 1)
);

this.#mapInstance.removeLayer(tileLayerWebGL);

code2:
addTileLayerWebGLToMap(map, source, constrainedExtent) {
    if (source) {
        const tileLayerWebGL = new TileLayerWebGL({
            source: source,
        });

        if (tileLayerWebGL) {
            map.addLayer(tileLayerWebGL);
            source.getView().then((v) => {
                v.resolution = v.resolutions[v.zoom];
                // v.extent = constrainedExtent;
                delete v.extent;
                delete v.resolutions;
                // delete v.zoom; 
                return v;
            })
        }
        return tileLayerWebGL;
    }
}

attempts
also the following code does not result in removing the TIFF overlay
this.#geoTIFFSource.on('tileloadend', (evt) =>{
    this.#geoTIFFSource.clear()
})

